# Calculating Values inside ArrayList

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an Array List that i am getting Values from the EditText widget  and placing them inside an Array List

I would like to do a Calculation and output the total to a Text View

The Program is Running fine it just crashes when i hit Calculate..

```
ArrayList<String> score = new ArrayList<String>();
 public class MyActivity extends Activity {
 EditText T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9;
 TextView total;

 int sum = 0;
Button ButtonClear, ButtonScore;
ArrayList<String> score = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    T1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    T2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    T3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    T4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    T5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    T6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
    T7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText8);
    T8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText9);
    T9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText10);
    total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView28);

    ButtonScore = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonScore);
    ButtonClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClear);


    score.add(T1.getText().toString());
    score.add(T2.getText().toString());
    score.add(T3.getText().toString());
    score.add(T4.getText().toString());
    score.add(T5.getText().toString());
    score.add(T6.getText().toString());
    score.add(T7.getText().toString());
    score.add(T8.getText().toString());
    score.add(T9.getText().toString());

 public void Calculate(View v)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < score.size(); i++)
       {
            sum = Integer.valueOf(score.get(i));
       }
       total.setText(sum);
   }
```

Comment: and what exception You get? Please post the logcat

Comment: Use `total.setText(sum + "");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting integer value to textview therefore it crash,So change

```
 total.setText(sum);
```

to

```
 total.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
```

And to calculate `sum` do like

```
sum += Integer.valueOf(score.get(i));
```

Comment: i placed in  
       total.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
But still now luck

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""

Comment: @David what is line number 149?

Comment: Line 149 is Sum +=Integer.valueOf(score.get(i));

Comment: @David Then check edittext values,Is there all edittext having values in number?

Comment: @David post logcat exception?

Comment: Same issue  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity invalid int: " "